# Sublime Text 2 - .txt files no longer triggering Markdown Editing

Tags: sublimetext2, markdown

As of this morning, Sublime Text 2 no longer triggers the Markdown Editing layout when I open .txt files. It still works fine with .md files though. Is anyone else having this problem? Is there anyway to troubleshoot what the problem is?

Answer (score 4):

Go to: View / Syntax / Open all with current extension as… / Markdown

And no, Markdown is *not* a default for `.txt` files, so if you want that, you will have to set it up as the default.

Comment: @user3070330 You’re welcome! Please [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) if it solved your problem to mark the question as resolved.